# How can I set color in Android referencing another color?

Tags: android, colors

In my Android App I have colors defined like this:

```
<color name="gray">#DDD</color>
<color name="white">#FFF</color>
<color name="black">#000</color>
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
```

I want to set a primary color for elements so it references another of my colors:

```
<color name="primary_color">[[RED]]</color>
```

So I can set default color to red. This helps defining a color in all the app and also allows to quickly change it in one place.

Using a reference like @color/red does not work.
Also, I do not want to use styles, since I want to reuse the color in places with already defined styles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can't be done. Best approach is to use styles.

Comment: why @color/red  doesn't work?

Comment: You are right, it works. I don't know why it didn't work for me when I checked. Thank you